# java signalr don't receive message when app is closed

Tags: android, android-studio, signalr

I'm using `SignalR`. I can receive Messages and show Notification when the app is open or is in the background. but when closed application I can't receive messages. Does anyone have a solution to this?

I have the following code in MainActivity `OnCreate`:

```
ActivityChat.connection.received(json -> runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
            public void run() {

                JsonObject jsonObject = json.getAsJsonObject();
                if (jsonObject != null && jsonObject.has("A")) {
                    jsonArray = jsonObject.getAsJsonArray("A");
                    String method = jsonObject.get("M").getAsString();
                    //PushNotifications(method,jsonArray);
                    if (method.equals("addNewMessage")) {
                        if (jsonArray != null && jsonArray.size() != 0) {
                            if (jsonArray.get(2).getAsString().equals(driverID)) {
                                if (TransportClass.showCaseView != null && !TransportClass.showCaseView.isShowing()) {
                                    Notificate();
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }));
```

Comment: **this is not an answer**, But i had a similar problem when i implemented notifications using firebase.  the problem was that when the app is not active/background then the notification is delivered to the device's system tray ,the data payload is delivered in the extras of the intent of your launcher Activity.  as i said this is not a solution but maybe its an option you should look in to

Answer (score 0):

This is by design, but not by the design of the SignalR client itself; this is a design consideration when building a mobile app on either native iOS or Android. When the app isn't in focus, the app isn't in the background running, either. AFAIK, in most cases the app is only running when you have it open on the phone. This is when the SignalR connection would be active - the moment you close the app, you also close the connection.

You'd want to use something like notifications here to tell the user to open the app, then when they do, the real-time connection would be there again.

Comment: Suppose the application is closed and there is a change in the database and I want to notify the user of this change. How to do it in Real-Time?